# .ajax will not POST, but will GET with no problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery's .ajax() function.  It seems like it should be pretty simple but for some reason I can't get the type: "POST" to work correctly.  Using type: "GET" works no problem, but "POST" doesn't seem to actually post anything to my accepting php script.  When I do a print_r($_POST) it returns me an empty array.  I've tried using both input type "submit" and "button" on the form input but it doesn't seem to change anything.  Any ideas why it's not working?

Ps - there are more than 1 forms on this page.

**Edit for Clarification**
If I do a print_r($_GET) when i use type:"GET", it prints out all the correct data, but if i change the .ajax option to type:"POST" and try to print_r($_POST) it shows a blank array with no content.

Js Code:

```
var dataString = 'reply_text='+ test + '&post_id=' + post_id ;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false
  });
  return false;
```

Form Code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="textboxcontent" name="reply_text"/>
<input type="submit" name="reply_submit" value="submit comment"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Where does the `dataString` variable used in your ajax request come from?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing.

Comment: Hi Darin, dataString comes directly before the .ajax request: var dataString = 'reply_text='+ text + '&post_id='+ post_id; And I know the dataString is working correctly because when I use GET it works fine. Should I be using a different string format?

Comment: ps - I've added the dataString to the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work better:

```
var text = ...
var post_id = ...

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process.php',
    data: { reply_text: text, post_id: post_id }
});
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I just tried that and still doesn't work for POST (though it still works for GET).

Comment: When you look at FireBug, do you see the parameters sent? I begin to suspect that there's something wrong with your server side script rather than the javascript.

Comment: oh wow great tip.  I checked FireBug and it was giving me a 302 for my POST.  The reason is that I'm using .htaccess to rewrite my URLs without the ".php" at the end.  In my js I was telling ajax to go to "process.php" when I just needed to send it to "process" (without the .php).  I can't believe that fixed it!  Thank you so much :D

Comment: @justinl great tip, that was EXACTLY what I was just doing, htaccess url rewriting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How do you hookup your event? Are you sure that it's beign triggered? Tried putting an alert or something in there, to make sure?

What does your `dataString` look like? `type: 'POST'` is enough to make the ajax callback a post, so it might be your data that's being passed in a bad manner.

Comment: I've updated the original question to answer your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post forms with AJAX, I suggest the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), which does so nicely and unobtrusively.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = {
    'test': $('input[name=text]').val(),
    'post_id': $('input[name=post_id]').val()
};

// process the form
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
    url: 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
    data: formData, // our data object
    dataType: 'html', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
    encode: true,
    success: function(updatedTable) {
        //alert(updatedTable);
        $('div#tableHolder').html(updatedTable);
    }
})
```